# AlpineJS bind every keydown in each <template> element

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Is this possible in alpine.js binding every keydown in each `<template>` element? What I want to achieve is every keypress(number only) will be put inside the `span` that is generated via `<template>`.

here's what I've done so far: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unknownymous/xcndk0uf/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! You should use the [`keydown` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) because `keypress` is deprecated. Just add the pressed numeric keys to an array and loop over it in the template code:

```
<body x-data="cb" @keydown="clickCapture">
<div id="container">
  <div class="input">
    <template x-for="key in keys">
      <span class="box" x-text="`${key !== undefined ? key : ''}`"></span>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('cb', () => ({
    keys: [],
    inputLength: 4,
    index: 0,

    init() {
      this.keys = Array(this.inputLength)
    },

    clickCapture(e) {
      if (e.key >= 0 && e.key <= 9 && this.index < this.inputLength) {
        this.keys[this.index] = e.key;
        this.index++;
      }
    }
  }))
})
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your response. this is some part of what I want to achieve, the purpose of  the inputLength in my jsfiddle(in your case `maxcase`?) is to display first how many boxes(span) will be rendered which is 4spans. then in those 4 span the keydown event will be display.

Comment: Right, see my updated answer. Now the 4 boxes are always displayed.